# How to reduce the complexity / nested ifs of this javascript time stamp builder function

Tags: javascript, nested

Hi I have a function which I have made which is designed to build partial ISO time stamps in line with an API that I am calling, an example of the time stamps it should return:

```
2017Z
2017-12Z
2017-12-24Z
2017-12-24T14Z
2017-12-24T14:07Z
```

the code which I use to perform this is as follows:

```
function parsePartialDateTime(datetime = {}) {
  if (datetime === null || datetime.year === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  let dateString = `${datetime.year}`;

  if (datetime.month) {
    dateString += `-${datetime.month}`;
    if (datetime.day) {
      dateString += `-${datetime.day}`;
      if (datetime.hour) {
        dateString += `T${datetime.hour}`;
        if (datetime.minute) {
          dateString += `:${datetime.minute}`;
          if (datetime.second) {
            dateString += `:${datetime.second}`;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return `${dateString}Z`;
}
```

I'm really not sure how I could remove the need for nested if functions as it should only build each element of the timestamp if the previous items are present (which are all supplied as a string / number in the datetime object.

Any help on this would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why do these need to be nested in the first place?

Comment: If the code works, it could be better to ask this on [codereview.se], but it's best to ask on their [meta.codereview.se]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the values in an array and loop over them:

```
// Just for brevity in this example
var dt = datetime;
// Put all the units you want checked in this array
var units = [dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second];

var dateString = dt.year
// Then loop over the array... 
for (let unit of units) {
    //... checking and adding like you were before
    if (unit) {
        dateString += `-${unit}`;
    } else {
        // So the rest of the object gets ignored
        break;
    }  
}
```

As noted in the comments though, this uses the same delimiter for each `unit`. It adds a small amount of complexity to resolve this:

```
// Each unit is paired with the delimiter that should be used on its left
var units = [[dt.month, "-"], [dt.day, "-"], [dt.hour, "T"],
             [dt.minute, ":"], [dt.second, ":"]];

var dateString = dt.year
// Deconstruct out the unit and the delimiter
for (let [unit, delim] of units) {
    if (unit) {
        dateString += delim + `${unit}`;
    } else {
        break;
    } 
}
```

Since every branch in your code takes the form of basically `if (x) y += x`, that can be extracted out fairly easily. If you're doing nearly the same thing over and over again, try reaching for a loop.

Comment: different delimiters for time components

Comment: @charlietfl Eww, you're right. I missed that. I'll get on my laptop and fix that up.

Comment: Not quite what he needs since it's supposed to stop building the `dateString` if a piece is missing.  This code will continue building the string if dt.month is missing but still has dt.minute.  Perhaps if you added `else break;` to end the for-loop if something is missing?

Comment: @SteveFrancisco I shouldn't have tried answering this like a minute after waking up :/. Ya, a break should fix that. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've had to modify it slightly so that it meets ES6 and Linting rules for however it has reduced the complexity, marked as answer as it solves the issue i was having :)